# How can i update multiple table with one query php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $user = json_decode($content, true);

    $id_a = $user['id_a'];
    $id_b = $user['id_b'];
    $aName = $user['aName'];
    $bName = $user['bName'];
    
    $sql = "
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE `tb1` 
    SET `aName` = '$aName' 
    WHERE `id_a` = '$id_a';
            
    UPDATE `tb2` 
    SET `bName` = '$nName' 
    WHERE `id_b` = '$id_b';
                
    COMMIT
    ";  
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result){
        echo json_encode(['status'=>'success','message'=>'Edited successfully']);
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(['status'=>'error','message'=>'An error occurred editing the information.']);
    }
}
else{
    echo json_encode(['status'=>'error','message'=>'REQUEST_METHOD Error']);
}
$conn->close();
```

I need to update data multiple table but when i use above code it it response "Edited successfully" but in database data didn't change anything

but when update single table it can

Comment: It would probably be easier to split $sql into separate queries. Executing multiple queries in one call is a chapter of its own.. Also, depending on what you use to communicate with the database there might be dedicated methods for handling transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a transaction because it seems your PDO does not accept a transaction.

Something like this should work in the example you gave:

```
  UPDATE tb1, tb2
    SET tb1.aName = $aName,
        tb2.bName = $bName
    WHERE
        tb1.id_a = $id_a
        AND tb2.id_b = $id_b;
```